# Telegram API: Get number of members in a group/channel using Telethon

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I've tried using the code below but it shows this error

> AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'full_chat'

```
from telethon import client
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetFullChannelRequest

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
client.connect()

channel_connect = client.get_entity(channel_name)
channel_full_info = client(GetFullChannelRequest(channel=channel_connect))
print(channel_full_info.full_chat.participants_count)
```

Comment: if it is claiming that it is a coroutine object it means it is an async function so you have to use it in an async function with await call
see this link to learn more about it https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html

Comment: @RaqunBob Which part of the code do I wrap with an async function?

Comment: I would try awaiting the line before last which is ```channel_full_info = await client(GetFullChannelRequest(channel=channel_connect))```

Answer (score 0):

it happens because full_chat is not an attribute of coroutine.

Here alternative using function "get_participants" from GetFullChannelRequest

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetFullChannelRequest


api_id = API ID
api_hash = 'API HASH'

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
if (client.is_user_authorized() == False):
    phone_number = 'PHONE NUMBER'
    client.send_code_request(phone_number)
    myself = client.sign_in(phone_number, input('Enter code: '))
channel = client.get_entity('CHANNEL LINK')

members = client.get_participants(channel)
print(len(members))
```